# How can ConfigSlurper's groovy file can call methods defined in build.gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am working on project whose build logic is defined in gradle and has a build.gradle file for it. Now, we would like to manage property of the project using groovy's config Sluper. And, I have placed config.groovy file in folder that contains all the Helper class for the project. The content of the conf.groovy file is below:

```
categories {
includeCategories = defaultIncludeCategories()
excludeCategories = defaultExcludeCategories()
}

String defaultIncludeCategories() {
   def include = 'default'
   if( isAbcJob() ) {
      include = 'tier0'
   }
   logger.info "defaultIncludeCategories: $include"
   include
}
```

Now, as you can see there is a method name isAbcJob() that I need to use in the configuration file but this method is present in build.gradle, which is the file that call conf.groovy file for property management.

Bottom line is how would conf.groovy script would know where isAbcJob() method is?

Please advice.

Comment: Why are you doing this rather than doing an `apply from:` to call a separate gradle script?

Comment: ie: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aconfiguring_using_external_script

Comment: @tim_yates I am new to Gradle so please bear with me.I have tried your suggestion and I am getting the error 'isAbcjob()' is not found. And, if you are suggesting to move all the methods that has participation in defining configuration to the new 'other.gradle' file then I guess it will be very difficult as there are so many methods. Also, these methods takes part in defining build logic as well.Please advice and if you could please explain in little detail about why I should not use configSlurper and why should I use the approach that you have suggested, then that would be great.

Comment: I just worry that the route you are taking will lead to a massively complex build script that will end up being hated by all. Can you come up with a simple example of what you're trying to do? Why is your build logic so complex? Why is configuration in the build?

Comment: @tim_yates The build logic is so complex as it is an inhouse-enterprise project and has 3000 lines of build logic. The problem is that there more than 40 labs in which this build logic is used to run jobs through Jenkins. So, one script is handling setting configuration for all these labs. Some of them are Windows, Unix, Mac etc. And, because there are multiple jobs, multiple platforms and multiple test domain involved, which makes it more complex. Right now, our build.gradle setup so many environment variables on the fly by looking at Job type etc.

Comment: @tim_yates Because of that we want to simplify property management as if something breaks it becomes difficult to keep track of the moving parts. Right now, my requirement is that: build.gradle <=====> other.gradle OR build.gradle <====> conf.groovy(configurationSlurper) know each other's method but as I am novice in Gradle I do not have clue how should I do it. Please suggest!

Comment: I would suggest using script plugins https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:types_of_plugins

Answer (score 0):

I found the following question that has been asked on Gradle forums very helpful. And, it looks like that accessing other gradle script's methods is not possible unless you access them through tasks:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/multiple-apply-froms-dont-seem-to-import-all-methods/2274/6

Comment: Please add a relevant part of the linked answer here.